# Recorded "Find+Replace All" macro finds only the first instance when run as a macro

Tags: vba, replace, find, ms-word

I set a user Find+Replace All macro, to find and replace all instances of a particular text, and it worked as planned.

However when I recorded that operation as a macro, and ran it, it replaced just the first instance of the find text. What am I doing wrong?

The code that was recorded is a further below.

```
Sub Macro25()
'
' Macro25 Macro
'
'

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Body Text")
    With Selection.Find.ParagraphFormat
        With .Shading
            .Texture = wdTextureNone
            .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
        End With
        .Borders.Shadow = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Body Text 2")
    With Selection.Find.Replacement.ParagraphFormat
        With .Shading
            .Texture = wdTextureNone
            .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
        End With
        .Borders.Shadow = False
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The macro is only replacing the text that you have selected when you run the macro. That's what the word `Selection` means.

If you want the Find/Replace to happen for your whole document, you need to replace `Selection` in your macro with `ActiveDocument`.

Comment: +1. I run the code pertaining to the `Selection.Find` object, and it replaces *all* instances of the `.Text` with the `.Replacement.Text`.  Alternatively, OP can define a `Range` object to refer to partial document, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
So moving on here ... below is the code I wrote myself. It is based on the code produced by the Macro recorder.
My code does not use the same idea of Selection. It uses a rng Range object.

However I get the same effect: that it is finding only the first instance of something.

```
Function ExecReplaceStyle(strSourceStyle As String, strDestinationStyle As String) As Integer
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim ret As Integer

        ExecReplaceStyle = 0
        Set rng = docActiveDoc.Range

        With rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(strSourceStyle)
            .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(strDestinationStyle)
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Forward = True
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchKashida = False
            .MatchDiacritics = False
            .MatchAlefHamza = False
            .MatchControl = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With

        rng.Select
        rng.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


        ExecReplaceStyle = ret

        Exit Function

    ErrorHandler:
        ExecReplaceStyle = Err.Number
        ErrDescription = Err.Description
        Resume Next
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll`  after the `End With` should search and replace across the whole document.